# Почему работает только 1 ссылка ajax?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Хочу сделать вывод постов через аякс. Записи выводятся так:

```
    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'category_name'=>'kvest', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>20)); ?>
    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="getContent" ><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
```

Скрипт аякс такой:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#getContent').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/content.php",
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
        $('#divContent').html('Получаем контент');
        },
        success: function(html){
        $("#divContent").html(html);
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
    });
    </script>
```

При этом срабатывает только первая ссылка.Остальные перезагружают страницу.Как сделать чтобы все ссылки работали?

Comment: id - это уникальное имя элемента, которое используется для изменения его стиля и обращения к нему через скрипты.
Оно же у вас стоит в цикле. Не надо так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю у вас ajax стоит тоже в цикле, так нельзя. И не валидно (хоть и будет работать) использовать несколько одинаковых id - он должен быть один.

Добавьте в ссылку аттрибут с урлом, например `data-url`

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-url="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>" class="getContent" ><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
```

И аякс который один раз после цикла вставлен и будет брать урл из аттрибута:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.getContent').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('data-url'),
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#divContent').html('Получаем контент');
            },
            success: function (html) {
                $("#divContent").html(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: спасибо добрый и умный человек!)